# codeigniter update ticket_status field with value "2" if one of the is_approved=1 based on orderid

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

This is **request** table

[image]

how can i update ticket_status field with value "2" if **one of** or  **atleast** if  is_approved=1 based on orderid

**This is what i have tried so for but it cant fill up all ticket status for respective orderid**

**This my Controller**

```
function pend_request($orderid){
        $this->load->model('request');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'order successfully pended');
        $this->request->pend_request($orederid);
        redirect('admin/Requests', 'refresh');
    }
```

**This is my Model**

```
 function pend_request($orderid)
    {
        $this->db->set('ticket_status', "2");
        $this->db->where('orderid', $orderid);
        $this->db->update('requests');
    }
```

**This is my View**

```
 <?php
       foreach($requests as $request):
    endforeach;
    if($request->is_approved == 1){?>
     <li>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/requests/pend_request/'.$request->orderid); ?>" class="btn btn-xs  btn-warning"><span class="icon-minus" style="color:blue"></span> pend</a>
 </li>
   <?php }
else{}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `is_approved=1` to limit the results since your getting all the items that has orderid of 16. not the orderid of 16 that is approved

**CONTROLLER**

```
function pend_request($orderid){
    $this->load->model('request');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'order successfully pended');
    $where = array(
       'orderid' => $orderid,
       'is_approved' => '1'
    );
    $this->request->pend_request($where);
    redirect('admin/Requests', 'refresh');
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function pend_request($where){
    $this->db->set('ticket_status', "2");
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update('requests');
}
```

Comment: @ Riyenz thanks. ticket_status field is updated with value="2" for is_approved="1" only. but what i need is it has to change the rest of ticket_status row also for orderid=16

Comment: change all orderid's ticket_status if one request_id has been approved? like removing the `'is_approved' => '1'` at `$where` **array**